# Asymmetric S-shaped function mapping interval $[0, 1]$ to interval $[0, 1]$

Tags: logistic, link-function

In the literature, is there any asymmetric $S$-shaped function that maps the interval $[0, 1]$ to interval $[0, 1]$?

Unfortunately I can't post figure so I just describe what I mean in text. The function I want should be monotonic increasing. In the meanwhile, for a real number $c < 0.5$, the function

$$0 \mapsto 0, \quad c \mapsto 0.5, \quad 1 \mapsto 1.$$

Moreover, the function is smooth on its domain, concave on interval $[0, c]$ and convex on interval $[c, 1]$.

By the way, can it be seen as a sort of link-function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

And here is how you go about finding one.

For our purposes, convex means $F''(x)\ge 0$ and concave means $F''(x)\le 0$.

Ok, so let $F$ be such a function. If we also assume monotonicity, we have $F'(x)\ge 0$, and $F$ is a cumulative distribution function. Therefore, the convex and concave conditions are $f'(x)\ge 0$ for $x\le c$ and $f'(x) \le 0$ for $x\ge c$ (where $f=F'$ is the pdf of $F$).

In other words, now we are looking for density function on $[0,1]$ that is increasing on $[0,c]$ and decreasing on $[c,1]$. We go to a table of probability distributions on $[0,1]$ (e.g., [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions)) and see that the cumulative distribution function of the [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) fits the bill.

Another approach would be to explicitly construct such a function (I believe a quartic would do the job).

Comment: Came to suggest Beta cdfs,... so all I can do is +1 your more extensive answer.

Comment: Bravo! Not only the answer but also the "derivation". Thanks also Glen_b!

Comment: Dear @pengsun.thu: I have rejected your proposed edit. I'm not sure whether or not you can see the comment I left when I did so, so let me repeat it here: In lieu of editing the answer, please clarify whether you really intended the function to be *concave* on $[0,c]$ and *convex* on $[c,1]$. Such a function will not look much like an $S$ (asymmetric or otherwise). Cheers. :-)

Comment: @pengsun.thu The answer belongs to Har, not me. I just upvoted it.

Comment: Well, sorry...I need time to get familiar with this nice website:)

Comment: @cardinal: Yes, I do mean concave on [0,c] and convex on [c,1]. To be precise, it looks like an "S" mirrored by the diagonal line y=x. I'm not sure how to call it as simple as "S-shaped function" so I simply say "S-shaped function" (Please do not hesitate to let me know if any). Excuse my English if that turns out to be a misleading description:) After all, it's a minor issue since the answer by Har has been good enough. I just try to make it consistent with my question.

Comment: @pengsun.thu: Thanks for the clarification. (+1) You can either reintroduce the edits or I will try to do so in a little while. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would comment instead, but I don't have the score yet, so here's my two cents:

The only thing I could think of is an asymmetric tangent function, yet I couldn't find anything about them except for [this part of the Proceedings of the Estonian Academy of Sciences, Engineering.](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=au16QkfTHZIC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=asymmetric%20tangent%20function&source=bl&ots=tbf7t56-CA&sig=7JV-PUyjUCBhsc2JwP6RMVu7wX8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Cc9GUcL4A43mkgWvxoDACw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=asymmetric%20tangent%20function&f=false) See if it helps...?

Comment: Yes, it dose! Very inspiring!! BTW, what is the motivation of such an asymmetric tangent in the domain of the paper you point to?

Comment: To measure finger arterial volume, V, as a function of its pressure, P, the inverse of the usual relationship P = f(V), and to be free of the limitations of equal sensitivity in positive and negative pressure, which isn't preferred with a symmetric model.

Comment: Interesting! It reminds me of the symmetric sigmoid function in neuro network, where the horizontal axis denotes "stimulus" while the vertical axis denotes "response". There should be a place for asymmetric tangent if the "response" to positive/negative "stimulus" is imbalanced.